# Field with @Field not getting translated to the correct value

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I have a document with one of the fields' names overridden by @Field:

```
public User {
@Id
private String id;
private String username;


@Field("profiles")
private List<BusinessProfile> 
businessProfiles;
...
}
```

And a aggregation operation with a match operation as follows:

```
match(where("businessProfiles.services").elemMatch(Criteria.where("category").is(serviceCategory)))
```

However, in the query that this ultimately generates, the businessProfiles is not traslated to profiles. Here is the query I got from the log files:

```
Executing aggregation: [ { "$match" : { "businessProfiles.services" : { "$elemMatch" : { "category" : "Cloud_Initiation"}}}} ...]
```

This behavior seems very odd. Is this supposed to work this way? Thanks.

Comment: Is the user class annotated with @Document annotation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Field mapping is only done for `TypedAggregation` providing the mapping source type.

```java
TypedAggregation<Product> agg = newAggregation(User.class, 
    match(where("businessProfiles.services")...
```

I created [DATAMONGO-2310](https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAMONGO-2310) to improve the documentation in that area.